# What would be the log(O(n * log(n)))?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I am currently learning about big O notation in my algorithms class and I stumbled upon this particular problem that perplexed me. Can we represent O(n lg(n)) as c * n* lg n if we know the formal definition holds? Meaning,  if f(n) <= c*n*lg n, and the definition holds true for some constants, then O(n lg n) can be represented as c* n* lg n? And if my assumption is true, then we could do:

= lg(O(n lg n))

= lg(c* n* lg n)

= lg(c) + lg(n) +lg(lg(n))

If lg(n) is the highest order term in this case, then would this simplify to be O(lg(n))? Since all the lower order terms would eventually be overlapped by the highest order term?

Comment: As `n` grows arbitrarily large, the `nlgn` term will behave like a constant times `n`, so you would be left with `lg(c*n)`.  So I think your reasoning is correct.

Comment: The problem you've posed is essentially nonsense. g(n) = O(f(n)) is an assertion about how fast g grows. O(.) isn't a function. So log(O(.)) is junk.

Comment: @Gene: Why do you think O is not a function? What is definition of a function?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi A function is a relation, which is a set (often infinite) of ordered pairs (x,y) where x is taken from a set called the domain and y is from a set called the range. For each such pair, we can write f(x) = y. Try to identify a domain and range for big-O. You won't be able to. It's a different notation, which just happens to resemble function notation.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [CompSci.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are totally right and your math is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little hard to follow. I think you are asking:

> Suppose we have a function `f` that grows asymptotically at or less than a rate of `O(n lg n)`.  Does the function `lg ∘ f` grow asymptotically at or less than a rate of `O(lg n)`?

Yes, it does.

UPDATE: Commenter Paul Hankin points out a counterexample. Perhaps this is correct?

> Suppose we have a function `f` that grows asymptotically at exactly a rate of `O(n lg n)`.  Does the function `lg ∘ f` grow asymptotically at a rate of `O(lg n)`?

I think the answer to that is yes.

Comment: exp(-n) = O(n lg n). But lg(exp(-n)) = -n which isn't O(lg n).

Comment: @PaulHankin: Hmm, a counterexample. Vexing! Though one wonders what it means for an algorithm's cost to grow *negatively linear*.

Comment: I think to fix it you need some restrictions on f. Either f = Theta(n lg n), or f >= 1 do the job I think.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Right, the problem is that "O" gives too loose a bound.

Comment: @PaulHankin Isn't Big-O applicable only to the functions which are monotonically non decreasing, by its definition?

Big-O is an upper bound on the worst complexity. for decreasing function its not the approximation to be taken

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: The formal definition is that you take the absolute value.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi I suppose it depends on the definition you're using. I've never seen a definition which requires big-O to have such restrictions on the functions it's describing (nor does the wikipedia page on big-O mention such a definition), but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @PaulHankin Your brilliant example actually spawned a discussion with my colleagues, and yes, you are right. With mere formal definition of Big-O both n and the function could be anything, But if Big-O is applied to functions denoting complexity of the algorithms then, domain of Big-O is range of a non decreasing function whose domain is whole number.

Comment: So if I am correct, Range of Big-O function on the Range of an monotonically decreasing function is actually 0?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show that `lg(O(n lg n)) = O(lg n)`. This is somewhat non-standard notation, but it means that for all `f` in `O(n lg n)`, there's a `g` in `O(lg n)` such that `log(f) = g`. This is explained on wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_usages

The statement isn't quite true as written. For example, `f = 2^(-n)` is in `O(n lg n)`, but `lg(f) = -n` which isn't in `O(lg n)`. But if we limit ourselves to `f`'s which are greater than `1`, then it's true.

If `f = O(n lg n)`, then there's a `c` such that for all sufficiently large `n`, `f(n) < cn lg n`. Then `lg(f(n)) < lg(c) + lg(n) + lg(lg(n)) = O(lg n)`. Since `lg(f(n)) > 0` , we have have that `lg(f(n)) = O(lg n)`. This is essentially your proof from the question with a little additional care taken about definitions and making sure that `lg(f(n))` isn't large and negative.